# Accessing custom line item meta submission data without $_POST

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I’m saving additional line item order item meta from custom form fields on the checkout page upon order creation using the hook `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` for  the addtional order item meta.

This approach works well when a) the user is logged in or b) users are guests and account creation is not allowed. However, when a user is creating a new customer account while submitting an order, $_POST isn’t available at `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` anymore, which means that the line item meta isn't added at all when a new user account is created in the the process of order creation.

So I've tried adding the line item data to the cart before the order is created at `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` when the $_POST is still available. For a test, I've done the following:

```
// $cart_content = WC()->cart->cart_contents;
// item ID of cart item, identified by dumping the cart-content, then exiting before the cart is cleared.
$cart_item    = WC()->cart->get_cart_item( '3b68ef3908441d858c425932f2379609' );
$cart_item['_check_this'] = 'Hello world!';
```

This will add a new array key to the specified cart item object with the value "Hello world!".

Sadly, either I'm doing it wrong or this approach doesn't work, because the variables available at `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` - $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order - don't contain the meta data added to the cart in this way, so the line item order meta can still not be created at that point.

I'm hoping I'm doing it wrong and would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Sorry but `$_POST` is available from `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` hook

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just tested again, and you're right. It's not $_POST that's missing. What doesn't work in case of the account creation is the nonce validation. The nonce key and value are present in $_POST in both cases. But if an account is created the verification fails -

`if ( ! isset( $_POST['woocommerce-process-checkout-nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['woocommerce-process-checkout-nonce'] ) ), 'woocommerce-process_checkout' ) ) {
wc_add_notice( __( 'Validation error', 'domain' ), 'error' );
return;
}`

Any idea why that may happen?

Comment: You don't need any nonce when using `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` to add order item metadata.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know! Although WPCS is flagging it if I don't check the nonce. I figured using the "process-checkout-nonce" would work for all checkout-process-related aspects ( and it does - except when an account is created, which I still find odd ).